# haxe add new key to object with variable

Tags: haxe

I have defined an object data that I use to store various bit of data I use for my code.   I want to insert a new room at runtime.  Eg a new key "R200" from a variable, but have not been able so far.

```
 static public var data = 
 {
    room: {
        "R100": {monstersLeft: 2 }
    }
 }


// need to add the the object data :
// would like to reference is like: 
var newRoom = "R200";
???? data[newRoom ].monstersLeft = 5;

trace(data.R200.monstersLeft)
```

Answer (score 6):

Haxe's [anonymous structures](https://haxe.org/manual/types-anonymous-structure.html) are nothing more than untyped, organised collections of data. Their structure is immutable once set and only the property values can be modified. Array access (bracket notation) is not defined on anonymous structures - instead, dot notation is used.

Because of the untyped (dynamic) nature of anonymous structures, they can have a [negative impact on performance](https://haxe.org/manual/types-structure-performance.html) when compiling to static targets.

It is recommended to organise and type anonymous structures by use of [typedefs](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-typedef.html) and [typedef extensions](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-extensions.html). This ensures type safety and helps the compilation server pick up on any typing mistakes on-the-go.

To get back on point, what you're trying to do is best achieved by use of [maps](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html) and typedefs. Maps let you store proper key-value pairs - both through methods and bracket notation - and typedefs let you type your data structure, ensuring type safety.

With that in mind, your code snippet could be recreated as follows:

```
class Test {
    static var data : Map<String, Room> = new Map<String, Room>();

    static function main() {
        data["R100"] = { monsterCount: 5 };
        data["R200"] = { monsterCount: 10 };

        trace(data["R100"].monsterCount);
        trace(data["R200"].monsterCount);
    }
}

typedef Room = {
    var monsterCount : Int;
}
```

`Room` is now a type described by the `{ "monsterCount": (Int) }` data structure, and is mapped to string keys which denote the room ID.

The Map API lets you set and remove key-value pairs from the map, as well as iterate over keys / values, and more. Make sure to check the [API docs](http://api.haxe.org/Map.html) for more information.

---

*Edit (2016-07-26)*

The answer provided by [lordkryss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670415/lordkryss) is perfectly valid. However, there are two main reasons why I didn't bring up [reflection](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html).

- Reflection is a runtime feature, its use would unnecessarily complicate your code and does not offer you the desired syntax.
- Reflection can be costly and unpredictable on different targets.

Generally you should fare better with reflection on dynamic rather than static targets. Keep that in mind when developing your project and deciding what your target platform will be.

I recommend looking into generated sources to better understand the impact of reflection. You can use the official [try.haxe.org](http://try.haxe.org/) sandbox to see Haxe 3.2.0 generated JavaScript source code. There is also the [unofficial sandbox](http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/) which also lets you see Haxe 3.3.0-rc.1 generated JavaScript source code.

Personally, *I do not think reflection is an acceptable solution to your problem*. I see your problem as one of finding the appropriate data structure to represent your data. Reflection has its use, but I would not recommend it in this case.

Answer (score 4):

While Domagoj's solution is probably a better solution to your problem, you can actually do what you ask in the question using [Reflection](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html):

```
class Test {
    static public var data = 
     {
        room: {
            "R100": {monstersLeft: 2 }
        }
    }



    static function main() {
        var newRoom = "R200";
        Reflect.setField(data,newRoom,{monstersLeft:5});
        trace(Reflect.getProperty(data, newRoom).monstersLeft);
    }
}
```

You can try the code at [try.haxe.org](http://try.haxe.org/#8b35d)

Comment: Thanks guys, All these answers are great.   I have gone with LordKryss answer for now, just because its the easiest to implement, but will go back and look at putting in the correct structure when I have it running.   Thanks Guys

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [haxe.DynamicAccess](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/DynamicAccess.html) it's a compile-time wrapper for Reflect. So it does not add any runtime overhead, but gives convenient syntax to manipulate anonymous structures.

```
import haxe.DynamicAccess;

typedef TRoom = {
    monstersLeft : Int
}


class Test {
    static public var data : {room:DynamicAccess<TRoom>} = {
        room: {
            "R100": {monstersLeft: 2}
        }
    };


    static function main() {

        var newRoom = "R200";
        data.room[newRoom] = {monstersLeft:10};

        trace(data.room['R200'].monstersLeft);
    }
}
```

You can try it here: http://try.haxe.org/#cBc45

Comment: I don't believe it's compile time, all reflection is done at run time. To compile time emulate what might look like reflection, you need to make use of macros.

Comment: I ment no additional overhead on top of reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [StringMap](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html) for this, since that is what you want :) a Map should be constructed like this: `[key => value, key => value ..]`. Note that you have [array access](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html) with this type of map, which gives you the syntax you asked for.

```
class Test {
    static public var data = {
        rooms: [
            "R100" => {monstersLeft: 2}
        ]
    }

    static function main() {
        // add room
        data.rooms["R200"] = {monstersLeft: 5};

        // read room
        trace(data.rooms["R100"].monstersLeft); // 2
    }
}
```

Demo: http://try.haxe.org/#2B855

This is not really the question, but to avoid the reflection completely you could use an Array instead of the object. This is an architectural change, the choice to use it depends mostly on how much you want to search the room by its id. If that is quite often, then use a map, otherwise this can be considered.

```
class Test {
    static public var data = {
        rooms: [ 
            {id:"R100", monstersLeft: 2},
        ]
    }

    static function main() {
        // add room
        var newRoom = {id:"R200", monstersLeft: 5};
        data.rooms.push(newRoom);

        // find rooms
        var room100 = findRoom("R100");
        trace(room100.monstersLeft); // 2
    }

    static function findRoom(id:String) {
        for (room in data.rooms) if (room.id == id) return room;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://try.haxe.org/#8bFfD